# An application should not attempt to recover from OutOfMemory?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

As by [sonarsource](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/error-handling/RSPEC-1181):

> Catching either Throwable or Error will also catch OutOfMemoryError
> and InternalError, from which an application should not attempt to
> recover.

Now, if was in a transaction, shouldn't I try to rollback it? Or would I cause a even worst state in the database? Aren't the resources released when OutOfMemoryError is created, so that I can use the memory again?

Answer (score 0):

Recovering from an `OutOfMemoryError`might work in some of the most simple cases, but often this error happens somewhere in library code and gets propagated to the user code that tries to handle it - while any intermediate objects from the point of the OOME to the point catching the exception might be in an inconsistent state. So unless you are 100% sure you can undo any changes to any objects that might have been modified in your `try`-block you better don't start trying.

Concerning transactions: any sane transaction-manager will automatically roll back any transactions if it loses the connection to an application without receiving a commit, so this should not be something you have to do manually.